How can I make an internal class in Kotlin visible in one other Module?
I have a set of information that should only be usable in two libraries: the library it is defined in and one other library which is closely related. I don't want other clients of the first library to have access to this property/class.
I have set the class to internal visibility, which takes care of not having it visible in the whole system. How can I make it visible in the related library/module?
I have found references to using associateWith like this
kotlin.target.compilations.run {
    getByName("funTest").associateWith(getByName(KotlinCompilation.MAIN_COMPILATION_NAME))
}

However, this only works when the two modules are compiled in the same project. I need to be able to do the same thing across projects.
I also found a syntax like this:
compilerOptions.freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xfriend-paths=/project/src/main")

However, it doesn't actually work during compile nor in IntelliJ .... so I must be missing some small detail

You might like a Gradle-esque solution to this problem.
If you have a multimodule Gradle setup with two projects, eg:
- projectOne
    - src/main/kotlin
    - build.gradle.kts
- projectTwo
    - src/main/kotlin
    - build.gradle.kts
- build.gradle.kts
- settings.gradle.kts

and projectOne depends on projectTwo as an implementation dependency:
// projectOne/build.gradle.kts

dependencies {
    implementation(project(":projectTwo"))
}

then any the projectOne code will be able to see classes and interfaces defined in projectTwo (where not marked as internal), but any projects that use projectOne as a dependency will not.
In fact, the same approach would work even if projectOne and projectTwo are separately published.

Thank you for your explanation.  However, one piece is missing. I am specifically looking for a way for projectOne code to see classes marked internal in projectTwo

I suggest working with the intentions of the Gradle/Kotlin designers, such as in the way I've outlined. Accessing an internal class in another project is fighting tooth and claw against the design of Kotlin. (Having said that, I believe there is some kind of (strongly discouraged) hack out there.)
